# How to reproduce "resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired " error on local machine in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am running oracle database and I am getting error as "resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired " and because of this error i am getting some other exceptions. on my local machine I am not getting this "resource busy ..." error. basically I want to reproduce this error on my local machine . is there any way to reproduce this error manually on my local machine?

Comment: The resource is most likely "busy" because of an uncommitted transaction that is preventing whatever else you are trying to do, similar to the example provided in the answer from Balazs Papp.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite clear what you want, this is a generic example of ORA-00054.

Session 1:

```
SQL> create table t1 (c1 number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (1);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Session 2:

```
SQL> truncate table t1;
truncate table t1
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired


SQL>
```